# Wordpress: Fix too many linked .CSS file in my index page (homepage)

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Upon my experience in other environments of IT, reading too many small files increases I/O time too much.
In my [wordpress site](http://etude.design), I have viewed source of my index page and understand that my homepage contains 46 linked css files.

Since each .CSS belong to different plugin beside of my theme, I want to know are there any method to bundle all these css files in Wordpress in order to decrease I/O and number of requests required to load my page.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ask this question on the [WordPress StackExchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for code-based solutions, but a quick answer is there are many plugins that will help with this kind of optimization, for instance the free plugin [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/).

Comment: I don't know why I felt that my development questions did not gain enough attention in wordpress stackexchange and after a while I tried to ask my questions over here! But thanks for your help.